# HTTP Error when uploading images over specific dimensions

Tags: theme-development, multisite, themes, uploads, errors

Hello I have a reseller account with one wp 3.5 multisite on a shared hosting.

Suddenly I can't upload photos after some random dimensions(It uploads the small sized ones just fine, but it has problems with the bigger ones).Specific any photo over than 511(width) i got http error , and any image less than 511(width) upload without any http error

**Operating System :** Linux (64 Bit)

**Server:** LiteSpeed

**Apache version:** 2.2.23

**Entry Processes:** 20

**Virtual Memory Usage & Physical Memory Usage:** 1048576 KB (each)

**I/O Usage:** 1024 KB/s

**My PHP specs:**

- **PHP Version:** 5.3.18
- **mysql Client API version:** 5.1.65-cll
- **post_max_size** 60m (Local Value) - 60m (Master Value)
- **upload_max_filesize** 100m (Local Value) - 200m (Master Value)
- **memory_limit** 1024m (Local Value) - 1024m (Master Value)
- **max_input_time** 60 (Local Value) - 60 (Master Value)
- **max_execution_time** 3600 (Local Value) - 600 (Master Value)

**functions.php of my theme:** http://pastebin.com/ddEQqVJy

My multisite .htaccess is

```
    # BASIC SECURITY
   <IfModule mod_security.c>
   <Files async-upload.php>
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
    </Files>
    </IfModule>
    #<IfModule mod_security.c>
    #SecFilterEngine Off
    #SecFilterScanPOST Off
    #</IfModule>
    php_value memory_limit 1024M
    php_value max_execution_time 3600
    php_value post_max_size 60M
    php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
    </IfModule>
    #php_value memory_limit 128M
    #php_admin_flag safe_mode off
    # Prevent folder browsing
    Options All -Indexes

    <Files wp-config.php>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
    </Files>

    # BEGIN feedburner and uploaded files adjustments.
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*(FeedBurner|FeedValidator) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^feed/?.*$ http://feeds.feedburner.com/mysite [L,NC,R=302]
    RewriteRule ^home?.*$ http://feeds.feedburner.com/mysite [L,NC,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ http://mysite.com/files/$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^wp-content/gallery/(.*)$ http://mysite.com/files/$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/jw-player-plugin-for-wordpress/player/player.swf$ http://mysite.com/files/jw-player-plugin-for-wordpress/player/player.swf$1 [L,R=301]
    </IfModule>

    # BEGIN ANTISPAMBLOG REGISTRATION
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .wp-signup.php*
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !.mysite.com. [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
    RewriteRule (.*) http://die-spammers.com/ [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .wp-comments-post.php*
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !.*mysite.com.* [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
    RewriteRule (.*) ^http://%{REMOTE_ADDR}/$ [R=301,L]
    </IfModule>

    # BEGIN Watermark Hotlinked Images
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://([^.]+\.)?mysite.com  [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://([^.]+\.)?google.\ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://([^.]+\.)?facebook.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://([^.]+\.)?twitter.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://([^.]+\.)?yahoo.\ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://([^.]+\.)?bing.\ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://([^.]+\.)?ixquick.com  [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://([^.]+\.)?feeds.feedburner.com/mysite  [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*\.(png|gif|jpe?g))$ http://mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/watermark-hotlinked-images/watermark.php?img=$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END Watermark Hotlinked Images

    #Begin gzip and deflate
    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
     AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css application/x-javascript text/plain text/xml image/x-icon
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType text/html M3600
    ExpiresByType text/css M3600
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript M3600
    ExpiresByType image/bmp M3600
    ExpiresByType image/gif M3600
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon M3600
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg M3600
    </IfModule>

    # BEGIN WordPress
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]

    # uploaded files
    RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
    #END WordPress
```

Update:
This is my functions.php of my theme http://pastebin.com/ddEQqVJy

We find the problem , the problem is on

line 131

```
add_image_size('theme-thumb', 520, 497, true);
```

lines 267-275

```
if (function_exists('add_theme_support')) {
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    set_post_thumbnail_size(150, 250); // default Post Thumbnail dimensions
}

if (function_exists('add_image_size')) {
    add_image_size('post-thumb', 310, 9999); //300 pixels wide (and unlimited height)
    add_image_size('widget-thumb', 220, 180, true); //(cropped)
}
```

When we took them off it didn't show any "HTTP error" when we uploaded a photo on media.

on function.php of Twenty Twelve
use

```
// This theme uses a custom image size for featured images, displayed on "standard" posts.
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 624, 9999 ); // Unlimited height, soft crop
```

without giving any "HTTP error" is strange, do you know why is this happening? And how can I fix it?

Comment: What's the HTTP error? Do you have any custom image sizes defined (in your theme or through any plugins)? Do you have any image-related plugins enabled? What happens if you upload other non-image files, e.g. a PDF, that's larger in file size than an afflicting image?

Comment: @MatthewBoynes 
Yes, I have custom image sizes and plugins(Smush it). I tried by dissabling all the plugins and I have also tried and another theme and still nothing. With .exe,.zip,.doc files I got this msg “xxx.zip” has failed to upload due to an error
Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons. with .pdf uploaded right, with .mp3 freeze at "Crunching…" But I uploaded it.... I returned back to the version 3.4.2 and everything works fine, so the problem occurs with the new version.

Answer (score 1):

Using LiteSpeed with php 5.3 + Wordpress 3.5 will require to increase **External App >> lsphp5** to these values :

> Memory Soft Limit = 777M
>
> Memory Hard Limit = 800M

Amazing values for memory setting, but it works for me.

Comment: ok i sent it to my host this suggestion :), thnx

Comment: can do this,  it is a shared server, he are not allowed to change the default values. :/